# Which t3 EC2 instance should i pick as a start when launching a spring/angular webapplication?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have built a spring boot/angular web application that uses a mySQL database for storage. The web application's main purpose is to be like a social media website for gardeners. Next to this it has a couple of tools that allow the user to generate a personalized planting calendar based on the monthly average temperature curve of the region where the user lives. Alternatively the user can also generate a personalized planting calendar based on planting journals made by other users that live within a certain radius near the user doing the calendar generating. I am using Hibernate Search for this.

I do not expect to get millions of visits in the first months after launching the web application, so my question is: What would be the best ec2 instance type to start out with? Could a t3.micro support an application like that for the first months or two? Also, How will i know when the current instance type can no longer handle the incoming traffic without lag and therefore i need to upgrade to a bigger instance like t3.medium or large?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the instance is suitable or not depends on many things. Based on my experience a micro instance is not enough for many use cases.

My suggestion is to start with a t3.small instance, start gathering metrics in CloudWatch to establish your baseline for few days. Then decide if it is enough or not.
If you are filling all your resources you can eventually upgrade to a bigger instance. However if your app is dealing with Java I think that a medium size is the minimum start.

About the lag and other things, first suggestion is to put CloudFront on top of the EC2 at least for all your static content (suggestion: put your static contents on S3 don't let EC2 serve them). Then I think that the only option is to rely on some third party performance tool, external to AWS.

By the way, I have built the same app on iOS many years ago, with a support website hosted on AWS. Now the app is gone, and the website is unmaintained :-)